# Gradle plugin for Intellij: How to set '--warning-mode all' to avoid the deprecation warning when running a program

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle-plugin

I am using the Gradle plugin. At the end of the build it says:

"Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings."

But I have no idea to pass a command line option to Gradle in IDEA. I've read several suggestions to add it to the gradle.properties folder but it doesn't exist for me.

I've tried adding it to gradle-wrapper.properties but that isn't correct and doesn't change anything.

Preferably I suppose I would like to not use any deprecated gradle features.  I downloaded the latest version online not sure why any of the features should be deprecated in any case.

Has anyone ever solved this before?  Other answer to questions hasn't fixed the issue and I seem lost on this.

Answer (score 4):

Use `org.gradle.warning.mode=(all,fail,summary,none)` in the [`gradle.properties` file](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:gradle_configuration_properties).

Comment: Thank you.  Yes I saw this in the log after but I couldn't figure out where the gradle.properties file was located.  The easy fix was just to create the file.  Feel silly for not doing that from the start haha.

Answer (score 3):

To disable this warning add the property `org.gradle.warning.mode=None` to the [gradle.properties](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:gradle_configuration_properties) file, either at project level or at a global level.

**gradle.properties**

```
org.gradle.warning.mode=None
```

**To disable it globally**

Append it to a `gradle.properties` located at the `.gradle` folder in the user home directory.

To do so in one step, run:

```
mkdir -p ~/.gradle && echo "org.gradle.warning.mode=None" >> ~/.gradle/gradle.properties
```

Below the valid values as per the [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/logging/configuration/WarningMode.html)

| Enum Constant | Description |
| --- | --- |
| All | Show all warnings. |
| Fail | Show all warnings and fail the build if any warning present. |
| None | No deprecation warnings at all. |
| Summary | Display a summary at the end of the build instead of rendering all warnings into the console output. |

**Environment**

```
Gradle 8.3
JVM 17.0.8 (Azul Systems, Inc. 17.0.8+7-LTS)
Mac OS X 13.4.1 aarch64
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem I and other people were having was locating the gradle.properties file.  Actually, I could have just created it.  Solution:

If your build doesn't have the gradle.properties file just create the file in the project directory.
In the directory, write the following command: org.gradle.warning.mode=all   [this will log whatever is deprecated]
Fix the issue or you can just eliminate the warnings altogether if you so choose.
Hope this helps someone it was driving me nuts.